# 'Get-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V' stucked on 20%

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-5.0

I have executed below command :

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V | Select-Object InstallState
```

It got stucked on 20%

[image: loading]

I waited for 30 mins but still no response.

Any specific reason and how I should I get rid of this ?

Powershell Version :

[image: PSVersionTable]

Answer (score 0):

You might try instead  the command :

```
Install-WindowsFeature –Name Hyper-V –IncludeSubFeature –IncludeManagementTools
```

But I would recommend when having such a problem to reboot and install Hyper-V via
*Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or
off*.

Comment: How about this? `DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V /NoRestart`